# How do I evaluate several n-th derivatives of a function at one point?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I have a question where I have to compute a `Table` containing $f^{(n)}(0)$ for `n = 1, ..., 5`, where $f^{(n)}$ denotes the $n$th derivative of $f$.

For the function $f(x)=x\mathrm{e}^{-x}$, I have:

```
f[x_]:=xe^-x
Table[D[f[x],{x,n}],{n,1,5}]//TableForm
```

How can I solve for the value of each derivative at 0?

Comment: Closely related: [How to find the nth derivative?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9598/121)

Answer (score 17):

Since Vitaliy already answered the question, I'll just add another answer to confuse you. To get the general form of the $n$-th derivative, you could use the properties of the *Taylor series* as follows:

```
Clear[n];
c[n_] = FullSimplify[SeriesCoefficient[n! x Exp[-x], {x, 0, n}], 
  n >= 0]
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  -(-1)^n n & n\geq 1 \\
>  0 & \text{True}
> \end{cases}$

This is the $n$-th coefficient in the series expansion of your function around $x = 0$ (with the factorial $n!$ canceled). It is the thing you're supposed to tabulate. To verify this, here is the table explicitly:

```
Array[c, {5}] // TableForm
```

> $\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ -2 \\ 3 \\ -4 \\ 5 \\\end{array}$

The nice thing about `c[n]` is of course that you no longer need to make such tables if you have a closed form for the derivatives. If you do want to make tables, though, then `c[n]` allows you to do this at very high speed because the definition `c[n_] = ...` using `Set` (the `=` sign) caused the right-hand side to be evaluated once and for all, so it doesn't have to be repeated every time you change `n`.

Comment: Nice touch ;) +1

Answer (score 13):

You have 2 typos. No space in `xe` and use capital `E` not `e` - or better `Exp[x]`

You have nicely behaving functions, so this would work:

```
f[x_] := x Exp[-x]
Table[D[f[x], {x, n}] /. x -> 0, {n, 1, 5}]
```

> {1, -2, 3, -4, 5}

But this is dangerous and it is better to use this:

```
f[x_] := x Exp[-x]
Table[Limit[D[f[x], {x, n}], x -> 0], {n, 1, 5}]
```

> {1, -2, 3, -4, 5}

To illustrate, imagine you have other function:

```
f[x_] := SinIntegral[x]
Table[D[f[x], {x, n}], {n, 1, 5}] // FullSimplify // Column
```

[image]

Using `/.x- > 0` will now give error due to `x` in denominator, while `Limit` is fine:

```
f[x_] := SinIntegral[x]
Table[Limit[D[f[x], {x, n}], x -> 0], {n, 1, 5}]
```

> {1, 0, -(1/3), 0, 1/5}

Comment: Okay thank you, makes sense adding the limit.

Comment: (+1) I hope we're not giving away anything that was in some homework problem...

Comment: Finding a derivative at 0 by taking the limit as `x -> 0` in the "general" formulate for the derivative can be dangerous: a function may be differentiable at a point yet that derivative need not be continuous there.

Comment: @murray Evaluation via substitution will go wrong in presence of a removable singularity. Evaluation via limit might go wrong in presence of a discontinuity in the derivative. The latter will, most often, be the less serious mistake. The best to be said for the blind substitution approach is one can try to trap for Indeterminate and switch to a limit. of course if you have (explicit zero)/(hiddfen zero) then the trap fails (Limit can also miss such things but is less likely to do so).

Comment: NestList[D[#, x] &, f[x], n] will avoid internally recomputing lower derivatives.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau very nice ;)

Answer (score 6):

Finally, this is supported by *V11.1*:

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn111.html

```
$Version
f[x_] := x E^-x
D[f[x], {x, n}]
```

[image]

Comment: I think you should show just the output of `D[f[x], {x, n}]`.

Comment: @CarlWoll Oh you're right. I was too excited...

Answer (score 5):

There is another approach that sometimes works better (gives closed-form expressions rather than recurrence relations):

```
In[1]:= InverseFourierTransform[(-I k)^n FourierTransform[1/(1 + x^2)^Log[2], x, k] , k, x]
Out[1]= (2^(-1 + n - 1/2 Log[1/x^2])
      Abs[x]^-Log[2] ((-I)^
      n ((1 + n) x Gamma[(1 + n)/2] Gamma[
      n/2 + Log[2]] Hypergeometric2F1[(1 + n)/2, n/2 + Log[2], 1/
      2, -x^2] (n + Log[4]) - 
    2 I Gamma[1 + n/2] Gamma[
      1/2 (1 + n + Log[4])] ((1 + x^2) Hypergeometric2F1[(2 + n)/
         2, 1/2 (1 + n + Log[4]), -(1/2), -x^2] - 
       Hypergeometric2F1[(2 + n)/2, 1/2 (1 + n + Log[4]), 1/
         2, -x^2] (1 + x^2 (3 + 2 n + Log[4])))) + 
 I^n ((1 + n) x Gamma[(1 + n)/2] Gamma[
      n/2 + Log[2]] Hypergeometric2F1[(1 + n)/2, n/2 + Log[2], 1/
      2, -x^2] (n + Log[4]) + 
    2 I Gamma[1 + n/2] Gamma[
      1/2 (1 + n + Log[4])] ((1 + x^2) Hypergeometric2F1[(2 + n)/
         2, 1/2 (1 + n + Log[4]), -(1/2), -x^2] - 
       Hypergeometric2F1[(2 + n)/2, 1/2 (1 + n + Log[4]), 1/
         2, -x^2] (1 + x^2 (3 + 2 n + Log[4]))))))/((1 + n) 
       Sqrt[Pi] x Gamma[Log[2]] (n + Log[4]))
```

It also can be used to find repeated anti-derivatives.

Comment: This does work, but only if the function decays fast enough to infinity. I don't think it will work for any kind of polynomials. E.g., try `x^2`:  you get `indeterminate` errors (with `n=1`).

Comment: You can use `x^2 UnitBox[a x]` to workaround this. This approach only _sometimes_ works better. In many cases it is not able to find the transform.

Comment: BTW, there is another cool use for this method: to prove that the Dirac delta function is the limit of the sinc function, one can do this: `InverseFourierTransform[
Limit[
FourierTransform[Sin[\[Omega] t]/(\[Pi] \[Omega]),\[Omega],\[Tau]],
t->\[Infinity]],
\[Tau],\[Omega]]` (I actually don't know any better way of getting that result in *Mathematica* because of the conservative way `DiracDelta` is defined).