# How do I get a general form for n-th derivative of a function?

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis

I tried the following but it basically returns unevaluated:

```
In[1]:= D[ArcTan[x], {x, n}]
Out[1]= Derivative[n][ArcTan][x]

In[2]:= FunctionExpand[Derivative[n][ArcTan][x], Element[n, Integers] && n > 0]
Out[2]= Derivative[n][ArcTan][x]
```

Is it possible to request Mathematica to expand it as a function of two variables `x, n`?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21701/134).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I know two approaches to this:

```
In[1]:= FullSimplify[SeriesCoefficient[ArcTan[y], {y, x, n}] n!, Element[n, Integers] && n > 0]
Out[1]= 1/2 I ((-I - x)^n - (I - x)^n) (1 + x^2)^-n Gamma[n]
```

and

```
In[2]:= FullSimplify[InverseFourierTransform[(-I k)^n FourierTransform[
          ArcTan[x], x, k] , k, x], Element[n, Integers] && n > 0]
Out[2]= 1/2 I (-(-1 - I x)^n + (1 - I x)^n) (I (1 + x^2))^-n Gamma[n]
```

The latter approach also could be used to find repeated indefinite integrals.