# How to implement symbolic Ramanujan's summation in Mathematica?

Tags: symbolic, summation, sequence

How to implement [Ramanujan's summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation) in symbolic form in Mathematica?

For instance, I want as input the function $f(x)=x$, as output $-1/12$, as input $f(x)=1/x$, as output $\gamma$ (Euler's constant).

Comment: Have you looked at the existing Ramanujan functions currently available in Mathematica?

Comment: Well, actually I really tried to solve this problem for a while on the day you raised this question, but finally be confused and worn out by the definition in the wikipedia page. There seems to be several **different** definitions in wiki, and none of them produces the desired result, maybe I didn't understand them correctly...

Answer (score 7):

The first result can be obtained using Dirichlet regularization:

```
Sum[n, {n, 1, Infinity}, Regularization -> "Dirichlet"]
```

> -(1/12)

The second can not be obtained, though. I don't have enough smarts to know if this is because it would actually require different regularization, or that Mma just doesn't know how to handle this case.

Comment: Ramanujan's summation applies not only to power series, so Zeta regularization is not applicable in the majority of cases. One of the general formulas is $$-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ g^{(n-1)} (0)}{n!} B_n(1)$$ for $g(x)=\Delta [f(x)]$ but how to get it in closed form?

Comment: @Anixx What's the definition of $\Delta[]$?

Comment: @xzczd  difference delta, f(x+1)-f(x).

Comment: @Anixx Seems to be another invalid definition: `f[x_] = x; g[x_] = DifferenceDelta[f[x], x]; -NSum[
 BernoulliB[Floor@n, 1]/n! Derivative[n - 1][g][0], {n, Infinity}]` produces `-0.5`.

Comment: @xzczd this is correct, my comment is somewhat confusing. The ramanujan's sum of g(x)=1 is indeed -0.5. In the comment I meant that I want the Ramanujan's sum of the difference delta. I want a similar formula but giving symbolic results.

Answer (score 5):

OK, with your new formula I'm able to give an incomplete answer now. The difficulty in implementing the forumla

$$-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{B_n(1) f^{(n-1)}(0)}{n!}$$

is how to symbolically compute the n-th derivative, which is discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24699/1871). Use the solution in that post, we can easily obtain this:

```
ramanujanSum[f_] := 
 Block[{x, n}, 
  FullSimplify[
     -Sum[BernoulliB[n, 1]/n SeriesCoefficient[f[x], {x, 0, n - 1}], {n, ∞}], 
   n >= 1]]
```

*Notice that f should be a functional relation.*

It manages to handle some of the Ramanujan summation mentioned in the corresponding wikipedia page:

```
ramanujanSum[# &]
(* -1/12 *)
ramanujanSum[1 &]
(* -1/2 *)
Assuming[{k ∈ Integers, k > 0}, ramanujanSum[#^(2 k - 1) &]]
(* -BernoulliB[2 k, 1]/(2 k) *)    
Assuming[{k ∈ Integers, k > 0}, ramanujanSum[#^(2 k) &]]
(* 0 *)
```

But fails in others:

```
ramanujanSum[1/# &]
(* The output is wrong, which is expected: 
   the implemented formula doesn't apply to this sequence. *)
trouble = ramanujanSum[(-1)^(# - 1) &]
(*  Sadly Sum seems not to be able to handle the final summation. *)
```

How can one improve it? I've no idea at the moment.

BTW, I doubt if the Ramanujan summation for $(-1)^{n-1}$ is (as stated in the wikipedia page) $1/2$:

```
trouble /. Sum -> NSum // Quiet
(* 0.5 + 0.31831 I *)
```

Comment: One can use the filliwing formula alternatively: $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\Delta^{k-1}[f](1)}{k!}(-1)_k$$ where $$(x)_k=\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(x-k+1)}$$ is the Porchhammer symbol (failing factorial). AFAIK it is implemented in Mathematica, otherwise one should employ limits because the both numerfator and denomenator have poles at the points.

Comment: I think your method is not suitable for anything other the polynomials because in that case the sum becomes finite. Mathematica cannot find the infinite sums :-(.

Comment: @Anixx Yeah, the ability of `Sum` seems to become the new threshold.  BTW the new formula using `DifferenceDelta` is even harder to implement… p.s. I suggest you to add these formulas to the question rather than in the comment only.

Answer (score 1):

As Kirma correctly stated, the infinite sum of all natural numbers (Ramanujan's Summation) can be calculated in *Mathematica* through the Dirichlet Regularization denoted by:

```
Sum[n, {n, 1, Infinity}, Regularization -> "Dirichlet"]
```

However, the second part of your question is partially wrong which is why you're getting an incorrect answer. The Euler–Mascheroni constant gamma is defined by the limit as n goes to infinity of the harmonic series (the sum from one to infinity, or n in this case with the limit) of 1/k minus the natural logarithm of n. So in this case,

```
Limit[Sum[1/k, {k, 1, n}] - Log[n], n -> ∞]
```

returns `EulerGamma`, which is that constant that you're referring to.

I'm not sure how you do all of the cool formatting, but hopefully this helps!