# How to deduce the Ramanujan's summation of this series?

Tags: symbolic, summation, sequence

I have already asked [a similar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80442/how-to-implement-symbolic-ramanujans-summation-in-mathematica) about Ramanujan's summation in general but received no good answers. Now I am interested in this exact series:

$$\sum _{n\ge1}^\Re (24 n + 12 n^2)$$

Comment: what is $\mathfrak R$?

Comment: @glance, it's a notation indicating that the sum should be interpreted as a Ramanujan sum.

Comment: Anyway, did you already try using the formulae in your other post on $x^n$?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Sumthing like that ;-}

Comment: @Guess who it does not resolve symbolically.

Comment: Have you already seen [this](https://hal-unice.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01150208/document)? In particular, it gives the formula $$\sum_{k\geq 1}^{\mathcal R} k^n = \frac{1-B_{n+1}}{n+1}$$ or `(1 - BernoulliB[n + 1])/(n + 1)` in *Mathematica* code. You can then use this along with linearity to evaluate your sum.

Answer (score 5):

From solution provided by kirma to your previous [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80442/how-to-implement-symbolic-ramanujans-summation-in-mathematica)

```
Sum[24 n + 12 n^2, {n, 1, Infinity}, Regularization -> "Dirichlet"]

(* -2 *)
```

From solution provided by xzczd to your previous [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80442/how-to-implement-symbolic-ramanujans-summation-in-mathematica)

```
ramanujanSum[f_] := 
 Block[{x, n}, 
  FullSimplify[-Sum[
     BernoulliB[n, 1]/n SeriesCoefficient[
       f[x], {x, 0, n - 1}], {n, \[Infinity]}], n >= 1]]

ramanujanSum[24 # + 12 #^2 &]

(* -2 *)
```

From  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation)
$$1+2+3+\cdots +=-\frac{1}{12}(R)$$

Extending to positive even power, this give:

$$1+2^{2k}+3^{3k}+\cdots +=0(R)$$

```
24*(-1/12) + 12*(0)

(* -2 *)
```

Comment: @Anixx - since it gives the same result as other approaches shown in comments and other answers, I assume that you have a problem in general with Ramanujan summations.

Comment: it does not in general.

Answer (score 3):

Using the **Zeta** function you can calculate arbitrary expression like in your example.

```
g = 24 Zeta [-1 ] + 12 Zeta [-2]

(* -2 *)
```