# Series in Sum form

Tags: series-expansion

I know that "Series[..." puts a function in series form, but how to put it in a general sum form.

For example:

```
Series[Exp[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

> 1+x+x^2/2+x^3/6+...

and

```
Sum[x^n/n!, {n, 0, 10}]
```

> 1+x+x^2/2+x^3/6+...

But I want to get the `x^n/n!` from `Exp[x]`

**How do I do that?**

Comment: Closely related: [How do I evaluate several n-th derivatives of a function at one point?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16148/245) ... Mathematically, that's really a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesCoefficient.html)

```
f[x_] := Exp[x]
x^n*FullSimplify[SeriesCoefficient[f[x], {x, 0, n}], {n >= 0, n ∈ Integers}]
 (* x^n/n! *)
```

or:

```
 f[x_] := Sin[x]
 x^n*Simplify[SeriesCoefficient[f[x], {x, 0, n}], {n >= 0, n ∈ Integers}]
 (*(I I^n (-1 + (-1)^n) x^n)/(2 n!)*)

 f[x_] := Sin[x]
 x^n*FullSimplify[SeriesCoefficient[f[x], {x, 0, n}], {n >= 0, n ∈ Integers}]
 (* ((-1)^(1 + n) x^n Sin[(n π)/2])/n!*)
```

Comment: wow, thanks! A bit complicated but that's not the point

Comment: @Ady. To simplify this, it probably is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

In M11 you can also use [`D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D) instead of [`SeriesCoefficient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesCoefficient):

```
x^n (D[Exp[x], {x, n}]/n! /. x->0)
x^n (D[Sin[x], {x, n}]/n! /. x->0)
```

> x^n/n!
>
> (x^n Sin[(n π)/2])/n!