# nth derivative on Wolfram Mathematica 9.0

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, version-9

I am running into an error when calculating the $nth$ derivative of some function
The code that I am using for determining it is

```
D[Sin[x],{x,n}]
```

The output should be $Sin$[$\frac{nπ}{2}$ $+  x]$.
But it is coming $(Sin)^n$$[x]$[image: The picture attached shows that the problem is with the nth derivative only, single and double derivatives are correct.]

Comment: What version are you on? I'm using 12.0 and I get the answer you expect.

Comment: @N.J.Evans I am using Mathematica 9.0

Comment: Have you tried closing Mathematica, then running your calculation again with a fresh notebook containing only `D[Sin[x], {x, n}]`?

Comment: Also, strongly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16148/1871 In short, the feature is added in _v11.1_. For earlier versions, please refer to the methods in the posts above.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Yes, I have tried everything from starting a fresh notebook and quitting a kernel and writing it once again. This error is coming when I calculate the nth derivative of any function.

Comment: @xzczd ohh so this syntax is not valid for the 9th version

Comment: Your syntax is fine and the answer you obtain is correct, just not very useful.

Comment: @bbgodfrey can you please be more elaborate?

Comment: If you executed `D[f[x], {x, n}]`, you would get an answer of the same form, but with `Sin` replaced by `f`.  So, your syntax is correct, and the answer is correct.  The difficulty is that Version 9 does not know how to reduce the general answer to the simpler form that you want.  In later versions, apparently it does.

Comment: Ohh ok thank you! @bbgodfrey