# I was wondering how to get the following result by mathematica or maple or other way

Tags: series-expansion

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I was wondering how to get the following result by mathematica or maple or other way

I have asked this question several days ago and recently I have got some new ideas,in the last equation of my new submitted pictures ,WE can got the simplest result of the left formula is!(1/\@(1 + t\^2 - 2\ t\ x)),so the right formula is also this result ,but in mathematica I get the result of thr right formula a Hypergeometric Function,so I was wondering how to get the simplest result as the left formula?

[image][image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One would hope that

```
Sum[t^n D[(x^2 - 1)^n, {x, n}] 2^-n/n!, {n, 0, Infinity}]
```

would yield the desired result, but it returns unevaluated.  However, according to [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendrePolynomial.html),

```
LegendreP[n, x] == D[(x^2 - 1)^n, {x, n}] 2^-n/n!
```

for `n` a nonnegative integer. Using this identity to rewrite the `Sum` then gives

```
Sum[LegendreP[n, x] t^n, {n, 0, Infinity}]
(* 1/Sqrt[1 + t^2 - 2 t x] *)
```

as desired.

As [Simon Woods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/862/simon-woods) noted in a comment below, Mathematica apparently cannot handle symbolic multiple derivatives.  With a specific value of `n`, for instance

```
With[{n = 30}, FullSimplify[LegendreP[n, x] == D[(x^2 - 1)^n, {x, n}] (1/2)^n/n!]]
(* True *)
```

Mathematica recognizes the identity.)

Comment: I don't think Mathematica can handle n'th derivatives for symbolic n. See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9598/862) for example.