# How to find nth log derivative using mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

Now I have a function, say $f(k,z)=e^{-kz}(1+kz)$

I want to find the $n$th $\log$ derivative with respect to z.
like $(z\partial_z)^{(n)}f(k,z)$ (or $(\partial_{\ln z})^{(n)}f(k,z)$
if you like), where the $(n)$ denotes that we take the derivative $n$ 
times.

I found the answer in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9598) quite helpful for me to find a general expression for $\partial_z^{(n)}f(k,z)$; however, I don't know how to generalize it to $\log$ derivative case using *Mathematica*. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider

```
logDiv[f_, n_] := Nest[z D[#, z] &, f, n]
```

which applies `z D[#, z] &` `n` times to `f`.  Then, for instance,

```
logDiv[k z, 2]
(* k z *)
```

or

```
logDiv[Exp[-kz] (1 + k z), 2]
(* E^-kz k z *)
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a nice closed form in terms of the Stirling subset numbers for these:

```
lDerivative[n_Integer?Positive][f_] := Composition[Function, Evaluate] @
(StirlingS2[n, Range[n]].Table[#^\[FormalK] Derivative[\[FormalK]][f][#],
                               {\[FormalK], 1, n}])
```

For instance,

```
lDerivative[8][f][x] == Nest[x D[#, x] &, f[x], 8] // Expand
   True

lDerivative[2][Function[z, Exp[-k z] (1 + k z)]][z] // Simplify
   E^(-k z) k^2 z^2 (-2 + k z)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
f[k_, z_] = E^(-k*z)*(1 + k*z);
```

Direct calculation using `Nest`

```
dOp1[f_, n_Integer?NonNegative] :=
 Nest[z*D[#, z] &, f, n]
```

`Simplify` at each step to reduce number of terms to be differentiated

```
dOp2[f_, n_Integer?NonNegative] :=
 Nest[Simplify[z*D[#, z]] &, f, n]
```

Transform for straightforward differentiation rather than differential operator

```
dOp3[f_, n_Integer?NonNegative] :=
 D[f /. z -> E^z, {z, n}] /. z -> Log[z]
```

Equivalent series expansion

```
dOp4[f_, n_Integer?NonNegative] :=
 Sum[StirlingS2[n, i]*z^i*D[f, {z, i}], {i, n}]
```

Comparing performance of the different approaches

```
m = 15;

g1 = dOp1[f[k, z], m]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {0.153352, Null}  *)

g2 = dOp2[f[k, z], m]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {0.11716, Null}  *)

g3 = dOp3[f[k, z], m]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {0.102199, Null}  *)

g4 = dOp4[f[k, z], m]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {0.000697, Null}  *)
```

Verifying that all results are the same

```
g1 == g2 == g3 == g4 // Simplify

(*  True  *)
```

Relative efficiency varies depending on order (`n`) and specific function (`f`).