# How to perform this nth derivative operation in MMA?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

I have to solve this following equation where I need to differentiate a function $n$ times.

$$A=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}\frac{s^n}{n!}(-1)^n\frac{d^nf(s)}{ds^n}$$

How to express the above equation in Mathematica?

Comment: nth derivative is not natively supported.

Comment: `Derivative[n][f][s]`.  But it's not clear at all to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: www.wolframalfa.com is natively supported for nth derivative.http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%28sin%28x%29,{x,n}%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**happy fish** ,he said **"nth derivative is not natively supported"** Yes it's **true**,but from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9598/how-to-find-the-nth-derivative?rq=1).

**Method1:**
For simple functions you can use InverseFourierTransform.

```
f[s_] := Sin[s];
nthDeriv1[f_, s_, n_] := FullSimplify[InverseFourierTransform[(-I k)^n FourierTransform[f, s, k], k, s], {n \[Element] Integers, n > 0}]
nthDeriv1[f[s], s, n]
```

$$\sin \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}+s\right)$$

```
A = Sum[s^n/n!*(-1)^n*nthDeriv1[f[s], s, n], {n, 0, m - 1}]
```

$$-\frac{i (\Gamma (m,-i s)-\Gamma (m,i s))}{2 \Gamma (m)}$$

**Method2:**
For analytic functions you can use SeriesCoefficient.

```
f[s_] := Sin[s];
nthDeriv2[f_, s_, n_] := Simplify[n!*SeriesCoefficient[f, {s, s, n}], {n \[Element] Integers, n > 0}]
nthDeriv2[f[s], s, n]
```

$$\sin \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}+s\right)$$

```
A = Sum[s^n/n!*(-1)^n*nthDeriv2[f[s], s, n], {n, 0, m - 1}]
```

$$-\frac{i (\Gamma (m,-i s)-\Gamma (m,i s))}{2 \Gamma (m)}$$

**For very difficult function both methods may not work!**

You can use a [MAPLE](http://www.maplesoft.com/) nth derivative is natively supported.

Comment: In V13, we can now just do `D[f[s], {s, n}]` instead of `SeriesCoefficient`.

Comment: @MichaelE2. For simple function works, but not for See: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/261196/closed-form-expression-of-the-n-th-derivative-of-a-function/261200#261200

Comment: I just mean that in earlier versions `D[]` would not evaluate if `n` was symbolic, not that it computes the n-th derivative for all functions.  You had to use `SeriesCoefficient` as you show in your answer, which seems a roundabout way to calculate it, when it can be calculated. BTW, `D[c^k E^(-c x) (-x + xu)^k, {x, n}]` gives me an answer that is satisfactory to me.