# Closed-form expression of the $n$-th derivative of a function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to simplify the $n$-th of this function
$$f(x)=e^{-cx}(c(x_u-x))^k,$$
where $x\in[0,x_u]$ and we know that $c>0$ is a constant and $k>0$ and integer.

I use `D[,{x,n}]` and after simplifying it, I get the following expression

```
n!y[2+n][n]
```

When I click on it, it says Difference Root and has three expressions.

Can anyone please tell what does this mean and how I can get a closed-form expression of the $n$-th derivative of $f$?

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: The command of Maple 2021 `diff(exp(-c*x)*(b - x)^k, x $ n) assuming k::posint,x>=0,x<=b,b>0` (`c^k` is a constant) produces `Sum(binomial(n, _k1)*exp(-c*x)*(-c)^_k1*(-1)^(n - _k1)*pochhammer(k - n + _k1 + 1, n - _k1)*(b - x)^(k - n + _k1), _k1 = 0 .. n)`

Comment: @user64494 thank you. This is my first time using mathematica so I'm not sure how to formulate a closed-form expression from what you posted!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like command `D[f[x], {x, n}]` fails for this function to get closed-form expression.

I found a [workaround](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113809/how-to-perform-this-nth-derivative-operation-in-mma/113829?noredirect=1#comment650274_113829):

```
ClearAll["`*"]; Remove["`*"];

f[x_] := c^k E^(-c x) (-x + xu)^k;
nthDeriv2[f_, x_, n_] := Simplify[n!*SeriesCoefficient[f, {x, x, n}], {n \[Element] Integers, n > 0}]
nthDeriv2[f[x], x, n] // FullSimplify;
SOL = FullSimplify[%, Assumptions -> {n \[Element] Integers, n > 0}]

(*(-1)^n c^k E^(-c x) (-x + xu)^(k - n)
Gamma[1 + k] Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[-n, 1 + k - n, c (x - xu)]*)
```

$$\frac{\partial ^n\left(c^k e^{-c x} (-x+\text{xu})^k\right)}{\partial x^n}=(-1)^n c^k e^{-c x} (-x+\text{xu})^{k-n} \Gamma (1+k) \, _1\tilde{F}_1(-n;1+k-n;c
   (x-\text{xu}))$$

We can check is my solution is `true` for example derivatives **10** times:

```
Table[(D[f[x], {x, j}] == SOL /. n -> j) // PowerExpand // FullSimplify, {j, 1, 10}]
(*{True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True}*)
```

**UPDATED:**

```
SOL // FunctionExpand  

 (* ((-1)^n c^k E^(-c x) (-x + xu)^(k - n)
Gamma[1 + k] Hypergeometric1F1[-n, 1 + k - n, c (x - xu)])/Gamma[1 + k - n] *)
```

Maple solution:

[image]

Mathematica and [Maple](https://www.maplesoft.com/products/Maple/students/) solutions are the same.

Answer (score 6):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] = E^(-c*x) (c (xu - x))^k;

df[n_] = D[f[x], {x, n}]
```

[image]

The [`DifferenceRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferenceRoot.html) can generate any desired derivative, for example,

```
df[3]

(* (1/((x - xu)^3))E^(-c x) (k^3 - 3 k^2 (1 + c (x - xu)) + 
   k (2 + 3 c (x - xu) + 3 c^2 (x - xu)^2) - c^3 (x - xu)^3) (c (-x + xu))^k *)
```

Comparing with other methods,

```
seq1 = (df /@ Range[0, 5]);

seq2 = NestList[D[#, x] &, f[x], 5];

seq3 = Table[D[f[x], {x, n}], {n, 0, 5}];
```

The methods are equivalent

```
seq1 == seq2 == seq3 // Simplify

(* True *)
```

**EDIT:** To get the series expansion, temporarily simplify the form of `f`

```
(df2[n_] = 
   D[E^(-c*x) (c*g[x])^k, {x, n}] /. {K[1] -> m, g[x] -> (xu - x)} // 
    Activate) // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
And @@ Table[df[n] == df2[n], {n, 0, 5}] // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Does this mean I can't get a closed-form for the $n$-th derivative? I'm still not sure how to get the formulation from mathematica's output!

Comment: [`DifferenceRootReduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferenceRootReduce.html) simplifies the difference root object somewhat.